# Datetime field expression error

Tags: apex

I'm getting the following error in the following method:

`Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Datetime`

method:

```
private Order_Activity__c createOrderActivity(string salesOrderId, string ownerId, string locationId, string recordtypeId, string activity, string status, string separation, string screen,
                                                        string ink, string workCenterId, datetime startTime) {
    Order_Activity__c oa = new Order_Activity__c();
    oa.Sales_Order__c = salesOrderId;
    oa.Sales_Order_Owner__c = ownerId;
    oa.Location_Number__c = locationId;
    oa.RecordTypeId = recordtypeId;
    oa.Activity__c = activity;
    oa.Activity_Status__c = status;
    oa.Separation_Status__c = separation;
    oa.Screen_Status__c = screen;
    oa.Ink_Status__c = ink;
    oa.Work_Center__c = workCenterId;
    DateTime dt = startTime;
    oa.Start_Time__c = DateTime.newInstance(dt.Start_Time__c.yearGmt(), dt.Start_Time__c.monthGmt(), dt.Start_Time__c.dayGmt(), 12, 0, 0);
    return oa;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
    oa.Start_Time__c = DateTime.newInstance(dt.Start_Time__c.yearGmt(), dt.Start_Time__c.monthGmt(), dt.Start_Time__c.dayGmt(), 12, 0, 0);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you debug dt value ?  also , I think you don't need to assign startTime .   Try this          oa.Start_Time__c = DateTime.newInstance(dt.yearGmt(), dt.monthGmt(), dt.dayGmt(), 12, 0, 0);

Comment: I don't think you mean `dt.Start_Time__c`. I think you mean just `dt`

Comment: Thank you Jeremy!! I needed another set of eyes on that one! Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyNottingham. Please post your comment as an answer to the question. Otherwise, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that the question didn't receive an answer. Dman100 will then be able to mark his question as solved by clicking the checkmark beside your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props to @amidstCloud, who basically gave the same comment as me.

The variable `dt` is a DateTime, and that's what you want to be evaluating. A DateTime has no fields or attributes; it should just be used directly. I would guess that the reference to Start_Time__c was left over from a previous version of your code.

```
oa.Start_Time__c = DateTime.newInstance(dt.yearGmt(), dt.monthGmt(), dt.dayGmt(), 12, 0, 0);
```